# How are RPM packages marked as "security" updates?

Tags: centos, rhel, security, rpm, packaging

If I am applying `yum install -y --security` and a package is updated; how is the package "marked" as a security update?

For example, lets say I have a package `blah` that I maintain, its current version is `1.18.3`. If I build a new package as `1.18.4` is it automatically a "security" package? If not, how/where is the documentation to mark the package as "security" update?

Comment: If you're building your own packages, you could also put all the security updates in a dedicated repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum` does this via [yum-security(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum-security) plugin which is part of `yum` (no need install it separately) for CentOS 7 ([official RHEL docs](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021)).

When you produce `yum update ... --security` `yum` download repository meta info updates in `/var/lib/<arch>/<repo>`. Each package in meta info file (organised as `xml` file) contains `type` field in `<update>` tag. If `type=security` then update is security update.

When you produce `yum update --cve <CVE>` or `yum update --bugzilla <bugzilla_id>` then `yum` analyses tag `<references>` for tags `<reference>` of each package in meta info for field `type` contains `bugzilla`. If you typed `--cve` then `CVE` comparison to `title` field of `<reference>` tag. If you typed `--bugzilla`, then `bugzilla_id` comparison to `id` field of `<reference>` tag.

The `update_md.py` file from `yum` package contains described upper functionality:

```
$ rpm -ql yum|grep update_md
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/update_md.py
```

P.S. Debian packages (DEB) contains `urgency` field in packages changelogs is might be useful for security updates.

Comment: As of CentOS 7, --security doesn't work because there are no meta info for security updates on CentOs repo